# Activating filter on subform causes value in dynamic column to display incorrectly

Tags: sql, ms-access

so I'm having a weird quirk in Access when trying to activate a subform filter using a button click, that calls a query that dynamically updates a column with a specific value.
To start off with here's the query we used to populate the column:

```
SELECT req.RequestID, req.[Broker Name], req.[Broker ID], req.Title, req.[Company Name], req.[Contact Name], [DT Num of Accts by Parent].[Total Number of Accounts], [DT num of hu rec by parent].[Total HU Recieved], [DT HU not recieved].[Total HU not recieved], req.DealID,
d.ID AS DealTableID,
SWITCH(
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FLOW Deal Executed] a WHERE d.ID = a.DealID), 'Contract Executed',
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FLOW Contract submitted] a WHERE d.ID = a.DealID), 'Contract Submitted',
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FLOW Deal Quoted] a WHERE d.ID = a.DealID), 'Quote Created',
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FLOW Deal Priced] a WHERE d.ID = a.DealID), 'Pricing Available',
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FLOW All HU Recieved] a WHERE d.ID = a.DealID), 'All HU Received',
    1=1,'Pending HU',
    ) As DealStatus
FROM (((Request req
    LEFT JOIN deal as d ON req.RequestID = d.RequestID) 
    LEFT JOIN [DT Num of Accts by Parent] ON req.RequestID = [DT Num of Accts by Parent].RequestID) 
    LEFT JOIN [DT num of hu rec by parent] ON req.RequestID = [DT num of hu rec by parent].RequestID) 
    LEFT JOIN [DT HU not recieved] ON req.RequestID = [DT HU not recieved].RequestID
WHERE (((req.DealID) Is Not Null));
```

This query appears to be working just fine and will display the column correctly in the subform (DealStatus) if there are no filters turned on. However when using a button to change the filter on the subform to only display specific values related to that column, the subform will display the correct RECORD, but the column will only display the default value of the column when all the switches are determined false (In this case "Pending HU")
Here is my onclick event (Fairly simple and just repeated for each button that needs it):

```
Private Sub Command56_Click()
    Child27.Form.Filter = "[DealStatus]='All HU Received'"
    Child27.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Further to this: I noticed that when the filter button is clicked the "DealStatus" column displays the correct value for a split second, before showing it's default value in the subform.

Anyone have any insight on having it display the correct value in the column?
Thanks

::EDIT::
Clarifying a bit of info (Specifically the buttons): We have 5 or 6 buttons that use the same, basic, onclick event to set the filter on the subform to match the string passed in the dynamic "DealStatus" column. It's when we use one of these buttons to change the filter that the problem starts.

::EDIT 2::
So I've been doing some digging and trouble shooting and I think it might have to do with the query itself. Although it appears to be working and returning the correct records according to the switch statement (And the other queries each switch statement is calling), whenever ANY filter is used on the query, it defaults the column "DealStatus" to the default value if all switch statements are chosen false (In this case pending HU). So maybe some insight on how to improve or fix the query?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean " here's the query we used to populate the column:" - That wuery looks like it returns multiple fields - what are you assigning to the ControSource for the column? Is that query the Recordsource for the subform? What is the column - is it DealStatus? I don't even see that fieldname in your query.

Comment: And what do you mean when you say you repeat the click event "for each button that needs it"?

Comment: The query is meant to populate multiple records, however the switch statement determines the dynamic column, thus the query is our record source for the subform. As I've said the query returns all the records we need it to, along with the dynamic column (Listed at the end of the switch statement "As DealStatus"). My problem lies in the data being displayed in the subform itself. As for the second point, I was just indicating that we have 5 buttons that share the same event procedure, just using a different filter status

Comment: Is your subfom a datasheet? What do you mean when you say "dynamic column" - is it unbound?

Comment: subform is a multi item subform, dynamic column is the column created by the query, and it is an unbound form